# initial sync not proceed on ops manager v2.0

Tags: mongodb

I try to get backup on ops manager.
but, initial sync is not proceed.
The following content and check the backup-agent.log has is displayed .

[backup-agent/components/mothership.go:321] Total Slice #1031 - server syncStore is full.  0th attempt.  Will resend this slice again soon.

I checked ulimit,head database space,back store space.but that is not full.
what is full?

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is a little ambiguous, Iam making couple of assumption.
Assumptions:
 - You are setting up the Ops Manager for an existing replica set.
 - The Agents are configured correctly and you have at least one Backup agent running on the replica set you are trying to backup.

Coming back to your question, syncStore is the OpLog Store which syncs your Initial Sync data using Backup Daemon. The issue here seems to be, backup job has not been bound to a headDB. you can do so by selecting Backup - Jobs - Job - under "Machine" label select set binding and select appropriate headDB.

Hope the above solution solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> [backup-agent/components/mothership.go:321] Total Slice #1031 - server syncStore is full. 0th attempt. Will resend this slice again soon.

Please note that server `syncStore` is full message indicates the `backup daemon` is not processing ( applying to `headDB`) the incoming `oplog/sync` slices fast enough.

Hence, In order to know the rate at which backup daemon is applying the slices to the `headDB` and track the status of the ongoing backup initial-sync process.

So you need to analyze `OpsManager`log files, there are-

1. Diagnostic archive log (`Admin-->General-->Overview-->System Overview-->Diagnostic Archive`)
2. Backup daemon logs and mms0 logs [available in `/opt/mongodb/mms/logs`]
3. Backup agent log

Thanks,

Karthick

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered the same problem because I did not place Mongo binaries in the mongodb releases directory during configuration. Because of this, the Deamon program cannot start the head database, resulting in the failure to take care of the transferred oplog, thus printing an error server syncStore is full.But that's not the reason.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30124766)